# align div content to right + use margin from right

Tags: html, css

I have a following problem, my div contend does not want to align to right. As you can see on the picture, my left side menu /blured/ is on the left + I used margin so it is not under each other like in an column, but it does not matter now. Menu links which should be aligned to right /whole div/, is on the left and when I try to use css float: right; it goes to right but content is aligned to left, So I can not make the menu symetric when I use the same margin as I used for left side. understand? I am struggling with it, please help.

jsfiddle>> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nrnL2wgt/)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYMy3.png)

HTML:

```
<body>
            <div id="tabulka">

                    <!-- LAVE MENU -->

                            <a class="uvod" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Uvod</a>
                            <a class="tim" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Tim</a>
                            <a class="sluzby" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Sluzby</a>
                    <!-- PRAVE MENU --> 

                            <a class="kontakty" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Kontakty ■</a>
                            <a class="ref" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Referencie ■</a>
                            <a class="odkazy" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Odkazy ■</a>


                    <!-- STRED LOGO, JAZYKY -->
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img src="imgs/logo2.svg" title="Logo" alt="alt">
                        </div>

            </div>

                    <div>       
                        <div id="switch">
                                        <img class="lang" src="imgs/sk.svg" title="SK" alt="alt">
                                        <img class="lang" src="imgs/en.svg" title="EN" alt="alt">
                                        <img class="lang" src="imgs/de.svg" title="DE" alt="alt">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  


    </body>
```

CSS>

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-image: url("imgs/repeat.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: #B20035;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#tabulka{
    background-image: url("imgs/fidal.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 600px;

}

#logo{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;

}

#switch{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70px;
}

.uvod{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.tim{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.sluzby{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}

#right{
    float: right;

    width: 0px;
}

.kontakty{
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.ref{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

.odkazy{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```

Comment: please post all relevant code, and if you can, create a jsfiddle that shows the issue youre talking about.

Comment: I added all relevant code to CSS, html is complete, and I cant create jsfiddle cause its kind of unique problem

Comment: i was more talking about the unfinished html code...cause theres a floating `</div>` tag. and if its kind of a unique problem that cannot be replicated, im sorry, but i wont be of much help. i however, i can help if i see the issue. gl though.

Comment: @indubitablee sorry man, I was not showing correctly but it was eventually there, can you check now please?

Comment: kk, looks like your image now. so what do you want this to look like? (i dont fully understand your explanation). i know you want it to float on the right hand side of the page. do you want it to be like a triangle? is that what youre talking about when you say margins?

Answer (score 0):

something like this? (revised based on comments)

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body{
    background-image: url("imgs/repeat.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
a{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#tabulka{
    background-image: url("imgs/fidal.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 600px;

}
#logo{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;

}
#switch{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70px;
}
.menu {
    margin-top:50px;
    float:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.odkazy {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.sluzby {
    margin-left: -110px;
}
.ref{
    margin-left: 65px;
}
.tim{
    margin-left: -135px;
}
.kontakty{
    margin-left: 115px;
}
.uvod{
    margin-left: -160px;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabulka">
    <div class="menu">
        <!-- LAVE MENU -->
        <a class="uvod" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Uvod</a>
        <a class="kontakty" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Kontakty ■</a>
        <br/><br/>
        <a class="tim" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Tim</a>
        <a class="ref" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Referencie ■</a>
        <br/><br/>
        <a class="sluzby" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Sluzby</a>
        <a class="odkazy" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Odkazy ■</a>
        <!-- PRAVE MENU --> 
    </div>
    <!-- STRED LOGO, JAZYKY -->
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="imgs/logo2.svg" title="Logo" alt="alt"/>
    </div>
    
</div>

<div>       
    <div id="switch">
        <img class="lang" src="imgs/sk.svg" title="SK" alt="alt"/>
        <img class="lang" src="imgs/en.svg" title="EN" alt="alt"/>
        <img class="lang" src="imgs/de.svg" title="DE" alt="alt"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah almost there, I meant a triangle upside down where left side is Uvod, Tim, Sluzby

Comment: @user3294564, i edited my answer, is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Revised code: copy, paste, save, launch. This should be what you want

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image: url("imgs/repeat.gif");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
width: 1024px;
background-color: #B20035;
margin: 0 auto;

}

a{
color: #fff;
font-size: 16pt;
font-family: Arial;
text-decoration: none;
}

#tabulka{
background-image: url("imgs/fidal.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 1024px;
height: 600px;

}

#logo{
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 40px;

}

.left a,
.right a {
display:block;
margin-top:50px;
}

#switch{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70px;
}

.left {
float:left;
text-align:left;
}

.right{
float:right;
text-align:right;
}

#uvod{
margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
}

#tim{
margin-left: 150px;
}

#sluzby{
margin-left: 200px;
}

#kontakty{
margin-right: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
}

#ref{
margin-right: 150px;
}

#odkazy{
margin-right: 200px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabulka">

<!-- LAVE MENU -->
  <div class="left">
      <a id="uvod" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Uvod</a>
      <a id="tim" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Tim</a>
      <a id="sluzby" href="uvod.html" target="_self">■ Sluzby</a>
  </div>
<!-- PRAVE MENU --> 
  <div class="right">
      <a id="kontakty" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Kontakty ■</a>
      <a id="ref" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Referencie ■</a>
      <a id="odkazy" href="uvod.html" target="_self">Odkazy ■</a>
  </div>


<!-- STRED LOGO, JAZYKY -->
  <div id="logo">
      <img src="imgs/logo2.svg" title="Logo" alt="alt">
  </div>

</div>

<div id="switch">
              <img class="lang" src="imgs/sk.svg" title="SK" alt="alt">
              <img class="lang" src="imgs/en.svg" title="EN" alt="alt">
              <img class="lang" src="imgs/de.svg" title="DE" alt="alt">
</div>                


</body>
```